# Proving that integral is larger than Wasserstein metric

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality, optimal-transport

I’m trying to understand a proof that appeared in a paper that I’m reading. The proof is about an inequality regarding the Wasserstein metric. My question is only related to showing that a particular integral is larger than the Wasserstein metric of two probability measures.

First, the p-th Wasserstein metric is given by:
$$
W_p(\nu,\mu):=\inf \left \{
\left(\int_{X^2}\mid x-y\mid^pd\pi(x,y)\right)^{\frac{1}{p}};  \pi\in P(X^2);\pi_o = \nu; \pi_1=\mu 
\right \}
$$

Where $\nu,\mu$ are probability measures and $\pi$ is a coupling of $\nu$ and $\mu$.

Now, let $T:X \rightarrow X$, and assume that
$$
\nu((-\infty,T(x)]) = \mu((-\infty,x]), \ \forall x \in \mathbb R
$$

Also, assume that $\mu$ is the standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb R$. How does one then shows that:

$$
\int_\mathbb R \frac{(T(x) - x)^2}{2} d\mu(x)\geq \frac{W_2^2(\nu,\mu)}{2}
$$

I believe that is not necessary for $\mu$ to be a Gaussian, because this was used in the a different part of the proof. But I included this information, since this is how it was presented.

Comment: So $X = \mathbb R$?

Comment: Yeah, you can consider $X$ to be the reals.

Comment: Consider the measure $\pi(x, y)=\mu(x)1_{y=T(x)}.$ This gives you a coupling of $\mu$ and $\nu$. And then note that the left side of your inequality is nothing by $\int |x-y|^2/2 d\pi.$

Comment: I think this $\nu$ would not satisfy the condition that $\mu((-\infty,x])=\nu((-\infty,T(x)])$.

Comment: I thought about using the product measure $\pi= \mu\times\nu$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think the answer by @dirich1337 is correct, there might be a simpler answer without using the Monge-Kantorovich equivalence.

What I came up with is the following. Let $\pi$ be the product measure, hence $\pi = \mu \times \nu$. This is indeed a coupling, so we immediately have
$$
\int_{X^2} (x-y)^2d\pi\geq W_2^2(\mu,\nu)
$$

The only thing left to show would be that using such coupling, we end up with the desired integral. Which is true, as shown below:
$$
\int y d\nu(y) = \int T(x) d\mu(x)
$$
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^2}(x-y)^2d(\mu\times\nu)=
\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}
(x-y)^2d\nu d\mu=
\\ =
\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}
x^2d\nu d\mu
-
2\int_{\mathbb R}x d\mu
\int_{\mathbb R}
y d\nu+
\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}
y^2d\nu d\mu =
\\
=
\int_{\mathbb R}
x^2d\mu
-
2\int_{\mathbb R}x d\mu
\int_{\mathbb R}
T(x) d\mu+
\int_{\mathbb R}
T(x)^2d\mu =
\int_{\mathbb R}(x-T(x))^2d\mu
$$

Answer (score 2):

First observe that T is a transport map, because $\nu=T_\#\mu$ is the pushforward measure of $\mu$ along $T$. This follows from the fact that intervals of the form $(-\infty,x]$ are Borel sets.

Since $\mu$ has a density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, the Monge-Kantorovich equivalence gives us that the optimal coupling $\pi$ is unique and $\pi=(Id, \tilde{T})_\#\mu$, for some transport map $\tilde{T}: X\to X$.
This implies that
$$\int_{X^2}|x-y|^2d\pi(x,y)=\int_X|x-\tilde{T}(x)|d\mu(x).$$

Your inequality therefore holds with equality iff $T=\tilde{T}$.

For a proof of the Monge-Kantorovich equivalence refer to [Computational Optimal Transport](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00567) Theorem 2.1 for a sketch. You will find references to more detailed proofs there.

Comment: Note: The Monge-Kantorovich equivalence is not needed to prove the inequality in question. You can just note that $(\operatorname{Id}\times T)_* \mu$ is a transport plan so that the Wasserstein distance is surely not larger than the costs of that plan.

Comment: Ah right! That’s much better.